Can get my pi 5 to recognise my nvme adapter
Could someone please help me! I've been struggling to get my nvme working so can boot up and use my ssd.
I've put in the config.txt dtparam=pciex1 and in the eeprom config PCIE_PROBE=1 and changed bootorder to 416 but to no avail, nothing!!!!! It's for the pi 5 and works through usb so know it works.
If anyone could help me if appreciate it soooo much. Thank you in advance
I've tried everything to my  knowledge and in raspi-config updated bootloader and boot order.
